# Is there a method that would allow me to add Python to an existing Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Install?

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to add Python to an existing VS2017 Enterprise installation?

- If I use the VS2017 installer to add Python, the disk space requirement includes all installed packages. I immediately get the "It looks like there is insufficient disk space..." message.

VS2017 reports insufficient disk space because large portions of Visual Studio must reside on the OS drive. I have Terabytes of space available on the target drive that I have specified.

- I do not want to uncheck existing items because the installer would remove them.  I simply want to add Python.
- I have downloaded the GitHub package for Python at https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/.

Is there a way to apply this to an existing installation of Visual Studio 2017 outside of the VS2017 installer without jeopardizing other languages?

Comment: You have to goto modify program then add python. Can't write an answer since I'm on my phone, and I don't have access to visual studio right now.

Comment: For VS2017, there is only an option to Uninstall.  There is no Modify.

Comment: You go into settings, after installation, not run the install again

Comment: If installing python is not working for you due to a disk space issue maybe you could use vs code?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

Comment: Hi Cricket_007 - what settings are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Ken - would really like a way to put this in VS 2017 IDE so that I can use source control and not introduce a learning curve for Code mid-project.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project, there's an option "Don't see what you're looking for? Open the Visual Studio Installer." From the installer, you can add new packages to your VS install.